# Ever increasing number of opened sockets on python web server

Tags: python, mongodb, sockets, flask, tornado

I have a simple python webserver and it keeps failing after 2 days/3 days. After investigation it is because it reaches its number of files opened limit. The opened files descriptors are sockets. (`ls -l /proc/pid/fd/xxx` : `/proc/pid/fd/xxx -> socket:[yyyyy]`)

I could increase ulimit but I would rather figure out what is going on.

**Some context**

- I have 50 machines that report every hour to the server that they are up and running, by a simple POST id=machine_id,cpu_usage=xxx
- the server simply stores this in a database (mongodb)
- there is a html page to monitor things, with some jquery/get json to make a chart of the cpu usage for a given machine over
- there is a handler for giving [(date, cpu_usage)] on GET?date_start,date_end,machine_id

I am the only one using this page, and as I said there are just 50 requests an hour randomly distributed to the server

the problem could stem from :

- jquery's `getjson` opened a socket and never closes it (could be but I don't think so as I restarted the server and didnt go on the monitoring page)
- the python code and the way I define the handlers in 'main'
- mongodb
- somewhere else I can't think of

code for main :

```
import listener_handler
from flask import Flask

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = Flask(__name__)

  listener_handl = None
  @app.route('/listener', methods=['POST'])
  def listener():
    global listener_handl
    if listener_handl is None:
      listener_handl = listener_handler.ListenerHandler()
    return listener_handl.Post()

  ... (other handlers for the getjson and the static monitoring page)

  app.run()
```

code for a handler :

```
from flask import request

class ListenerHandler:
  def Post(self):
    Save(request.form.get('machine_id'), request.form.get('cpu_usage'))
    return 'ok'
```

code for mongo db :

```
import pymongo

mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient()
mongo_db = mongo_client.stations_monitoring

def Save(machine_id, cpu_usage):
  mongo_db.db['monitoring'].save({'machine': machine_id, 'cpu': cpu_usage})
```

I tried to keep the code lightweight, I have good experience with python but almost none with python webserver so I don't really know what's going on under the hood when I define the handlers, if a new socket is created each time, if it is closed at the end, ...

I first had a flask server (code here) then moved to tornado (replaced `app.run` by a few tornado imports and some `IOLoop.instance().start()`) but this lead to the same problem

Comment: possibly stupid question but are those pymongo connections to mongod process that are hanging around?  not another part of your process?

Comment: You are right, I solved part of the problem some time ago. The socket has nothing to do with mongodb. It is between a remote computer (client) and the server. The client makes a connection, but its internet connection is crappy so it hangs for ever. Adding a timeout on curl helped. But I don't know why Flask or Tornado don't handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem between flask and pymongo; I solved it by cleaning up each request.  If you don't have performance reasons to leave the MongoClient handle open, you may as well close it.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.disconnect

```
import pymongo
class MongoConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        client = pymongo.MongoClient()
        self.db = client.stations_monitoring
    def close(self):
        self.db.disconnect()

def Save(machine_id, cpu_usage):
    mongoConnector = MongoConnector()
    mongoConnector.db['monitoring'].save({'machine': machine_id, 'cpu': cpu_usage})
    mongoConnector.close()
```

Flask is single threaded, your WSGI handler will spawn your desired number of individual applications, so you don't need to worry about thread support at the flask level.

If you really want to persist mongo connections and have a performance reason to do so, MongoClient supports AutoReconnect exception with a reconnect, so you should not have to handle it yourself.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo.errors import AutoReconnect

class MongoConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        client = pymongo.MongoClient()
        self.db = client.stations_monitoring
    def close(self):
        self.db.disconnect()

mongoConnector = MongoConnector()
def Save(machine_id, cpu_usage):
    try:
        mongoConnector.db['monitoring'].save({'machine': machine_id, 'cpu': cpu_usage})
    except AutoReconnect:
        #should be reconnected now
        mongoConnector.db['monitoring'].save({'machine': machine_id, 'cpu': cpu_usage})
```

[EDIT] no idea why yours isnt working.  Try simplifying what you are doing.  If you dont have a reason for your getters, just make it simple.

testflask.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)

def SaveLog(machine_id, cpu_usage):
    mc = pymongo.MongoClient()
    db = mc.stations_monitoring
    db['monitoring'].save({'machine': machine_id, 'cpu': cpu_usage})
    mc.disconnect()

@app.route('/listener', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def listener():
    SaveLog(request.form.get('machine_id'), request.form.get('cpu_usage'))
    return 'ok'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

test_get.py hammer the server with requests. Mine can do ~50/s

```
import requests
from random import randint

while True:
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/listener?machine_id=%s&cpu_usage=%s' %(randint(1,10000), randint(1,100)))
    print r.text
```

verify fds (mine hangs around 5-10 open file handles)

```
ps aux | grep testflask.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I @ bash -c 'ls -l /proc/@/fd/ | wc -l'
```

Comment: Many thanks. Just to be sure, you want to call close() after the `try/except AutoReconnect`, right ? But if you do so, how does it persist the connection for performance ? And if you don't, how does it solve the problem of closing the sockets ? Im not sure about what the doc says

Comment: no, the second example shows how I would persist a MongoClient object, mongoConnector would need to be open for the duration of the flask process (forever) and you are letting MongoClient class do the connection reconnecting for you.  In my situation, I used the first example of simply opening and closing the MongoClient handle because I did not have a performance problem requiring me to persist the connection.

Comment: I see what you are saying, you only see the print new connection happen once on startup?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your second example and mine, as you don't call `close()` explicitly. I didn't have any exception raised in my code either (although I see the point of AutoReconnect)

Comment: sorry, I dont think there is a difference.  Reconnect aside, I just didn't understand why you needed a getter function when you could just declare it.

Comment: I have put the thing in the getter to have a clean initialization but this was not so much the point. Closing the mongo client is indeed the right thing to do to make it work (close the sockets) but I am still not sure about your second solution and when to "close" etc and I will just cross my fingers and hope for pymongo to optimize the opening/close of the same connection many times

Comment: Sorry to make this go on forever but opening a client and calling disconnect at the end didn't make the thing work either. 1020 something sockets were opened after running 4 days. At least it worked for longer than last time

Comment: really weird, for the sake of trying, can you try my simplified version?

Comment: the simplified version (opening client, reading, disconnecting) is not working at all, reads return empty results

Comment: Adding max_pool_size=10, waitQueueMultiple=3 in MongoClient constructor didn't make it work either

Answer (score 0):

we are using pymongo + flask + gunicorn, and everything is ok. pymongo will maintain a connection pool, every MongoClient instance has a built-in connection pool. So, if you have too much running mongoclient instances, it may complain about too many open files.

[how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo)

Comment: Thanks for the link. They advise to open just one client but that's what I did in the first place (checking if mongo_client is None) and I had the bug. I started again with the max_pool_size etc arguments given in the doc and will see...

Comment: can you share the code of how you use pymongo, open the client, do a find or save, ... ? I have been stuck with this for 2 weeks now and still can't figure it out, thanks